# Auto scale image in html tag

Tags: html

Is there a way to get Firefox (or a browser in general) to scale an image in an HTML image tag automatically depending on the window size, and then expand the image to full size upon clicking on it, in the same way that the browser displays an image if you view it directly (right click and hit view image)?

Comment: lol ... no ... javascript, jQuery or other javascript libraries do that.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can't achieve the part where you want to make the image larger using click without some JS, but if you want the image to scale according to the browser size, you can use this in your CSS stylesheet:

```
img {
     max-width: 100%;
}
```

Read more about this [here](http://unstoppablerobotninja.com/entry/fluid-images/).